# How to process 2 lists using parallelStream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 groups of account number based on CAD and USD currency. Based on these lists I need to call same method by passing request parameters one for CAD and other for USD.

```
List<List<String>> accountNumberList = Arrays.asList(
      accountNumbersCAD, accountNumbersUSD
);
List<String> response = new ArrayList<>();
accountNumberList.parallelStream().forEach(s -> {
      String response1 = null;
      String response2 = null;
    try {
        response1 = performanceService.retrievePeriodData(reqCAD).toString();
        response2 = performanceService.retrievePeriodData(reqUSD).toString();   
    } catch (ApiException e) {

    }

      response.add(response1);
      response.add(response2);
    });

return (ResponseEntity<String>) response;
```

Please guide me on how to use `parallelStream`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly it is you want to do with these two lists?  The code snippet is not very clear.

Comment: Unless `s` is used, I don't see the point in using a stream, parallel or otherwise.

Comment: I haven't noticed it before but why don't you use `s` inside of the stream? What's the point of using a stream if you're not using its elements?

Comment: Still learning parallelStream, so might have coded it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't populate a list from a parallel stream using `forEach` because it will cause unexpected results and the resulting list size might be different each time. Instead use either synchronized list or populate the list using collect method.

```
List<Double> response = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

In my opinion mapping inside of the stream doesn't look complicated and there might be no sense of using parallel stream, compare performance of a sequential and parallel stream yourself.

As the second option you can use collect 2 times and it should be more efficient than using a synchronized List.

```
Function<PerformanceDataRequest, String> mapper = s -> {
    try {
        return performanceService.retrievePeriodData(s).toString();
    } catch (ApiException e) {}
 };

List<String> response = accountNumberList.parallelStream().map(mapper.apply(reqCAD)).collect(Collectors.toList());
response.addAll(accountNumberList.parallelStream().map(mapper.apply(reqUSD)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I don't know type of what is `reqCAD`/`reqUSD` so I put `E` instead.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the suggestion but its throwing error with map that "The method map(Function<? super List<String>,? extends R>) in the type Stream<List<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String)". also the type of reqCAD and reqUSD is PerformanceDataRequest (our own class).